# AngularJS $animate.addClass is not firing the addClass function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gsap

I have a couple of instances where I am performing animation with Angular.

They are both almost identical - yet one works,and the other doesn't - I can't figure out by the second one doesn't.

**The following, is the directive that DOES work:** - It essentially animates a bunch of child elements within the `element`

```
    dwApp.directive('introText', ['$animate', '$rootScope', function ($animate, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {            
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.animationStarted = false;

            $rootScope.$on('element-in-view', function (event, parent) {               
                if (!scope.animationStarted) {
                    scope.animationStarted = true;
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'slidein');
                };
            });
        }
    }

}]);


dwApp.animation('.slidein', function () {

    return {
        addClass: function (element, className) {
            TweenMax.staggerTo(element.children(), 2.8, { opacity: 0.85, left: '5%', ease: Circ.easeOut }, 3);  
        }
    }

});
```

**The following, is the directive that does NOT work** - the console logging shows that it all works, right up to `console.log('performing animation');` - telling me that the function is just not being fired, and i have no idea why...

**HTML is simply**

`<mask></mask>`

```
dwApp.directive('mask', ['$animate', '$rootScope', function ($animate, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log('mask directive')

            $rootScope.showMask = function () {
                console.log('showMask called - add class')
                $animate.addClass(element, 'showmask');
            };          

            // test
            $rootScope.showMask();
        }
    }

}]);


dwApp.animation('.showmask', function () {
    console.log('in showmask animation service');
    return {
        addClass: function (element, className) {
            console.log('performing animation');
            TweenMax.to(element, 1, { opacity: 1 });
        }
    }

});
```

When viewing the HTML source after `$rootScope.showMask()` has been called I can see that the mask now has the class

```
<mask class="showmask"></mask>
```

Does anybody have any idea where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is the way you're testing the `showMask()`.

If instead of

```
$rootScope.showMask()
```

you use

```
$timeout(function(){$rootScope.showMask()});
```

(And add the appropriate dependencies.) Then `'performing animation'` is logged as well; and presumably if I'd included `tweenmax` it'd have done something.

http://jsfiddle.net/zQfxq/

Someone else may have to fill in the finer details of why calling `$rootScope.showMask()` at that point doesn't work as you expect, but I think it makes sense to wait with testing till everything is compiled and linked; and that's what the `$timeout` does.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks. I guess, on a side-note, do you know how to watch AngularJS and have it fire an event when its finished compiling ?

Comment: No. (Not yet :P) And of course it has to compile every time it uses a new template; so it's not done after doing it just once. But `$timeout` without a time argument always fires after the current `digest` cycle is done.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use element variable for that?

```
element.addCLass('showmask')
```

Comment: Not sure if you read the entire question, though I'm not just adding a class... That coe simply adds the class to my element - that's not enough to kick off the actual animation. `$animate.addClass(element, 'myClassName');` does the same, though also supposed to call the addClass function in my `dwApp.animation()` service - it's part of angular-animate.js -